# How to do a data lookup field in a DetailsView?

Tags: asp.net

I have a master-detail page for Customers. Select a customer from the list and a details view opens with Name, Address...etc.

I've been asked to add a field listing the Sales Rep servicing that customer.

I want the new field to hold the foreign key to the SalesRep table: the  SalesRepID. An integer.

I am not sure how to "wire up" the ItemTemplate field for displaying the Sales Rep name in a label. Also not sure about the EditItemTemplate dropdown list of possible Sales Reps.

I know I need to create a datasource to retreive the Sales Reps into a dataSet.

Let's call it "SQL_Reps_source".

A DropDownList seems to only like a list of values, and doesn't seem to handle Keys and Values like a HashTable or SortedList would.

Any advice on how to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example adds a DropDownList to the EditItemTemplate of the DetailsView. The DataSourceID is set to the data source control that retrieves the sales reps names and id's.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sales Rep">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT SalesRepID, SalesRepName FROM SalesReps">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" Runat="server" 
            DataTextField="SalesRepName" DataValueField="SalesRepID"     
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SalesRepID") %>'
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label" Runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("SalesRepName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Question: How does the label find the proper Sales Rep from  the bound dataset? 

For example, let's say the customer record has SalesRepID of 15 stored in the CompanyRepID field. That's Frank Jones in the Sales Reps table.

So how does the ItemTemplate label get "Frank Jones" fromn the dataset of 100 salesreps?  Don;t you have to do the actual "lookup" somewhere?

Comment: You mentioned your using a 'master-detail' view for customers. The DetailsView is bound to a data source which uses the query specified in it's SelectCommand to lookup a record. I assume our master is passing the id of the customer to lookup to the datasource of the detailsview, through parameters. I can provide a more complete example is you would like.

Answer (score 0):

1. For display purposes - return the NAME of the Sales Rep. rather than ID
2. DropDownList (ddl) handles both Values and Keys just fine, the naming is a bit off though.  ddl.DataTextField property will hold the Name, ddl.DataValueField property will hold the ID. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627073/how-do-i-bind-a-list-to-a-ddl/1627094#1627094) for more details on this)
3. In the EditTemplate you'd need to fill the DropDown as described above, and then set its SelectedValue to the ID of Sales Rep. in quesion.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the dropdownlist do this:

```
ddl.DataSource = SQL_Reps_source;
ddl..DataTextField = "fullname";
ddl..DataValueField = "id";
```